# How to add watermark to aspose pdf and word that contain table

Tags: aspose.words, aspose.pdf

I generate a `Aspose.Generate.Pdf` file and then add a `Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Table`to it by following method. but when I add watermark to this pdf file, it covers by created table:

```
   public static BasketResult<string> ExportDataTableToPdf(DataTable inputDataTable, string CaptionFilename)
    {
        List<DataColumn> listDataColumns = GetDataColumns(inputDataTable, CaptionFilename);
        BasketResult<string> returnResult = new BasketResult<string>();
        String rtnPathFile = String.Empty;
        int rowCount = inputDataTable.Rows.Count;

        if (rowCount <= 1000)
        {
            try
            {
                string dataDir = Settings.TempPath;

                if (!Directory.Exists(dataDir))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(dataDir);

                Pdf pdfConv = new Pdf();
                pdfConv.IsRightToLeft = true;
                Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Section mainSection = pdfConv.Sections.Add();
                mainSection.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft = true;
                mainSection.IsLandscape = true;
                mainSection.TextInfo.Alignment = AlignmentType.Right;

                // header definition begin
                Aspose.Pdf.Generator.HeaderFooter header = new Aspose.Pdf.Generator.HeaderFooter(mainSection);
                mainSection.EvenHeader = header;
                mainSection.OddHeader = header;
                header.Margin.Top = 50;
                Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Table headerTable = new Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Table();
                header.Paragraphs.Add(headerTable);
                headerTable.DefaultCellBorder = new BorderInfo((int)BorderSide.All, 0.1F);
                headerTable.Alignment = AlignmentType.Right;
                headerTable.DefaultColumnWidth = "80";
                headerTable.FixedHeight = 30;
                Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Row headerRow = headerTable.Rows.Add();
                headerRow.BackgroundColor = new Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Color("#D3DFEE");

                int index = 0;
                listDataColumns.Reverse();

                foreach (DataColumn column in listDataColumns)
                {
                    string cellText = column.Caption;
                    headerRow.Cells.Add(cellText);
                    headerRow.Cells[index].DefaultCellTextInfo.FontName = "Tahoma";
                    headerRow.Cells[index].DefaultCellTextInfo.IsRightToLeft = true;
                    headerRow.Cells[index].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignmentType.Center;
                    headerRow.Cells[index++].Alignment = AlignmentType.Center;
                }

                Document doc = new Document();
                DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
                Aspose.Words.Tables.Table wordTable = ImportTableFromDataTable(builder, inputDataTable,
                    CaptionFilename, true);

                string columnWidths = "";
                for (int j = 0; j < wordTable.FirstRow.Count; j++)
                {
                    columnWidths = columnWidths + "80 ";
                }

                Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Table table = new Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Table();
                mainSection.Paragraphs.Add(table);
                table.ColumnWidths = columnWidths;
                table.DefaultCellBorder = new BorderInfo((int)BorderSide.All, 0.1F);
                table.Alignment = AlignmentType.Right;

                //fill table
                for (int i = 1; i < wordTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Row row = table.Rows.Add();
                    row.BackgroundColor = i % 2 == 0
                        ? new Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Color("#D3DFEE")
                        : new Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Color("#FFFFFF");
                    var wordTableRow = wordTable.Rows[i];
                    //fill columns from end to begin because table is left to right
                    for (int c = wordTable.FirstRow.Count - 1; c >= 0; c--)
                    {
                        var cellValue = wordTableRow.ChildNodes[c];
                        string cellText = cellValue.GetText();
                        row.Cells.Add(cellText);
                    }

                    //set style to every cell
                    for (int c = 0; c < wordTable.FirstRow.Count; c++)
                    {
                        row.Cells[c].DefaultCellTextInfo.FontName = "Tahoma";
                        row.Cells[c].DefaultCellTextInfo.IsRightToLeft = true;
                        row.Cells[c].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignmentType.Center;
                        row.Cells[c].Alignment = AlignmentType.Center;
                    }
                }

                pdfConv.SetUnicode();

                rtnPathFile = Helper.GetTempFile() + ".pdf";
                string fileName = Helper.GetFileNameFromFilePath(rtnPathFile);
                pdfConv = AddPdfWatermark(pdfConv);
                pdfConv.Save(dataDir + fileName);
                returnResult.Result.Add(rtnPathFile);
                returnResult.IsSuccess = true;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                rtnPathFile = String.Empty;
                returnResult.IsSuccess = false;
                returnResult.Result.Add(rtnPathFile);
                returnResult.persianErrorMessages.Add(Messages.Err_InvalidFilePath);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            returnResult.IsSuccess = false;
            returnResult.Result.Add(rtnPathFile);
            returnResult.persianErrorMessages.Add(Messages.Err_CreateFile);
        }

        return returnResult;
    }
```

and AddPdfWatermerk method is :

```
   private static Pdf AddPdfWatermark(Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Pdf pdfConv)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create FloatingBox with x as width and y as height
            Aspose.Pdf.Generator.FloatingBox background = new Aspose.Pdf.Generator.FloatingBox(); // width, height
            Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Image backImage = new Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Image();

            string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/images/PrivateExcelBackGround.png");
            byte[] bgBuffer = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            MemoryStream streamBack = new MemoryStream(bgBuffer, false);

            backImage.ImageInfo.ImageStream = streamBack;
            background.Paragraphs.Add(backImage);
            background.ZIndex = 1000;
            pdfConv.Watermarks.Add(background);

            pdfConv.IsWatermarkOnTop = false;
            return pdfConv;
        }
        catch
        {
            return pdfConv;
        }
    }
```

I tried stamp instead of watermark, but table masks it too.
in aspose.words.document file I have a problem too, in word file with mentioned table,watermark added correctly  but when a colored alternate table rows, watermark covered by colorful rows.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an out-dated version of Aspose.PDF API. Kindly upgrade to Aspose.PDF for .NET 18.1, which includes more features and bug fixes. You can add an image stamp by using below code snippet in your environment.

```
// Open document
Document pdfDocument = new Document(dataDir+ "AddImageStamp.pdf");

// Create image stamp
ImageStamp imageStamp = new ImageStamp(dataDir + "aspose-logo.jpg");
imageStamp.Background = true;
imageStamp.XIndent = 100;
imageStamp.YIndent = 100;
imageStamp.Height = 300;
imageStamp.Width = 300;
imageStamp.Rotate = Rotation.on270;
imageStamp.Opacity = 0.5;

// Add stamp to particular page
pdfDocument.Pages[1].AddStamp(imageStamp);

dataDir = dataDir + "AddImageStamp_out.pdf";

// Save output document
pdfDocument.Save(dataDir);
```

ImageStamp class provides the properties necessary for creating an image-based stamp, such as height, width, opacity etc. You may visit [Adding stamp in a PDF file](https://docs.aspose.com/display/pdfnet/Adding+Stamp+in+a+PDF+file) for further information on this topic. In case you notice any problem with the file generated by using this code, please get back to us with source and generated file so that we may proceed to help you out.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for aspose 9.3, and I can't to upgrade it because it needs a lot of changes in my code(aspose 18.1 doesn't know Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Pdf , ...)

Comment: Aspose.Pdf.Generator approach has been obsoleted and discontinued and DOM (Document Object Model) has been introduced which is enhanced and improved in terms of performance and features. Please upgrade to latest version, to rectify the watermark issue you are currently facing.